# Qual a utilidade do $ em uma expressão que executa um pipe em uma propriedade no Angular?

Tags: angular, operadores, nativescript

No [tutorial escrito por Jen Looper para o site Nativescript](https://www.nativescript.org/blog/create-a-twitter-clone-using-flexbox) ela demonstra um código que antes do pipe é precedido pelo simbolo `$` como abaixo:

```
<ScrollView>
    <StackLayout>
        <FlexboxLayout class="container" *ngFor="let yowl of (yowls$ | async)">                 
        </FlexboxLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Qual a função e efeito deste `$`?

Answer (score 2):

O Dollar no final de nomes de propriedades passou a ser uma convenção de linguagens não tipadas, ou fracamente tipadas, para facilitar identificar propriedades que sejam de tipos que contenham  o que ela realmente representa, por exemplo um `Observable` ou um `Promise`.
ps. Acabei encontrando a resposta no [Stackoverflow em Inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180213/the-dollar-sign), pesquisei por "dollar" no lugar do simbolo e obtive um retorno mais detalhado, ([dificuldade citada neste link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39874/search-terms-with-dollar-signs-are-ignored))

.

Sendo assim a propriedade irá ser um Promise ou Observable que fornecer um valor como seu resultado final.

Veja o [exemplo, obtido no manual do Angular](https://angular.io/guide/rx-library#naming-conventions-for-observables):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-stopwatch',
  templateUrl: './stopwatch.component.html'
})
export class StopwatchComponent {

  stopwatchValue: number;
  stopwatchValue$: Observable<number>;

  start() {
    this.stopwatchValue$.subscribe(num =>
      this.stopwatchValue = num
    );
  }
}
```

Veja que ambas as variáveis tem o mesmo nome inicial, a que é Observable é posfixada com Dollar para indicar tal característica. E a varável final que representa o mesmo valor, porém fora do Observable não tem tem o Dollar.

Em linguagens tipadas como TypeScript o uso de tal símbolo é como nomear uma propriedade usando seu tipo, como `nomeString`, acaba sendo informação descartável.

O uso do Dollar não interfere no funcionamento em nada, sendo valioso apenas, então, em linguagens não tipadas, porém uma boa prática.

Tal prática, historicamente, foi adotada no Framework [cyrcles.js](https://cyrcles.js)